# Cannot read property 'forwardingCounter' of null | Error while binding named model to SAPUI5 XML View

Tags: sapui5

Though odata, i am getting the results and binding the same to the view through named model as shown below. Some times, i can able to view the results and upon cliking refresh several times, i can view the data for some instance and unable to view the data in some cases. It is not consistent.

Below is the sample code.

```
var docInfoModel = new JSONModel(oData.results);  
oView.setModel(docInfoModel, "docInfoModel");
```

Comment: Sounds like a timing problem. Please share all of your relevant code.

Comment: Hi Alex, below is the sample piece of code......var popupModel = new JSONModel({
    title: "",
    totAmt: "",
    Money: "0",
    docRef: ""
   });
   var popupData = {};
   debugger;
   popupModel.setProperty("/", popupData); 
   this.getView().setModel(popupModel, "popupModel");   Once i click on the date of calender, onSelectedDate event, i have wrritten this logic. When i select date for first 2 times, i am getting error. When i select third time, it is success.

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forwardingCounter' of null
    at Function.h.addAPIParentInfoEnd (ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:599)
    at x.add (ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:535)
    at f.o.addAggregation (ManagedObject-dbg.js:2162)
    at f.addSuggestionRow (ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:312)
    at H (ManagedObject-dbg.js:4062)
    at f.o.updateAggregation (ManagedObject-dbg.js:4147)
    at A.update (ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:386)
    at f.l (ManagedObject-dbg.js:3885)
    at f.b.fireEvent (EventProvider-dbg.js:247)
    at f.B._fireChange (Binding-dbg.js:400)

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should definitely work

```
onAfterRendering: function(){    
  var docInfoModel = new JSONModel(); //Create JSON Mmdel   

  oModel.read("/MyEntity", {
    success: function(oData){
      console.log(oData); //Check in the console whether data is being returned
      docInfoModel.setProperty("/", oData.results); //Set data to JSON model
      this.getView().setModel(docInfoModel, "docInfoModel"); //Bind model to view
    }.bind(this)
  });
}
```